Why this Pandas DataFrame column operation fails?
This script works fine with Python 3.11 and Pandas 2.2:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(f'test.csv', comment='#')
df['x1'] = df['x1']*8
# df['y1'] = df['y1']*8
print(df)

and prints:
   x1   y1
0   0    0
1  16    6
2  32   12

but fails when I uncomment df['y1'] = df['y1']*8 and produces KeyError: 'y1'. Why is that? 'y1' is a valid key. Here is the test.csv file:
# comment 
x1, y1
0, 0
2, 6
4, 12


What if you say df[' y1'] = df[' y1']*8? Please note the preceding whitespace before "y1" in the CSV file.

@tshiono You are right, it was the whitespace. Thank you.

Read your file with the skipinitialspace=True option of read_csv
df = pd.read_csv(csv, skipinitialspace=True)

Columns:
['x1', 'y1']


I like this option. It allows for more readable .csv files, even if they may be in a gray area standard-wise.

@Paul CSV is unfortunately not a standardized format, therefore the plethora of option to handle all the variations.

That's not valid CSV. Admittedly, CSV is fuzzily defined, but gratuitous whitespace is asking for trouble. Try looking at the column names:
>>> df.columns
Index(['x1', ' y1'], dtype='object')

Pandas assumed that you wanted those spaces to be part of the column name.
Pandas did a good job at guessing the integers, but then python's native integer understands how to do that to
>>> int('   4')
4

You can strip whitepace after reading the csv
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(f'test.csv', comment='#')
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
df['x1'] = df['x1']*8
df['y1'] = df['y1']*8
print(df)

And if column data also has the same space issue (perhaps you have a column of strings), you can do the same thing there.

Thanks. I did look at Index(['x1', ' y1'], dtype='object') more than once and didn't notice the leading space :-(
